# Can any find the solution for this Error in IBM DB2?

Tags: db2, dataset, websphere

%sql select Name_of_School, Safety_Score from SCHOOLS where \
  Safety_Score= (select MAX(Safety_Score) from SCHOOLS)

i am trying to execute this query i got the message.

- ibm_db_sa://rbm44299:***@dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-lon02-04.services.eu-gb.bluemix.net:50000/BLUDB
  (ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: SQLNumResultCols failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0206N  "SAFETY_SCORE" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703 SQLCODE=-206
  [SQL: select Name_of_School, Safety_Score from SCHOOLS where    Safety_Score= (select MAX(Safety_Score) from SCHOOLS)]
  (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Comment: Is the column named "Safety_Score" with quotes or is it Safety_Score without quotes? Db2 is complaining that it is not a valid column

Comment: What's the exact result of `SELECT COLNAME FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE TABSCHEMA = CURRENT SCHEMA AND TABNAME = 'SCHOOLS' AND UPPER(COLNAME)='SAFETY_SCORE'`?

Answer (score 1):

`SQL0206N` is this error message https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic1.html#sql0206n

> SQL0206N name is not valid in the context where it is used.
>
> This error can occur in the following cases:
>
> For an INSERT or UPDATE statement, the specified column is not a column of the table, or view that was specified as the object of the insert or update.
>
> For a SELECT or DELETE statement, the specified column is not a column of any of the tables or views identified in a FROM clause in the statement.

among other cases.

I.e. Column `SAFETY_SCORE` does not exist in your table.  Maybe the column is `"Safety_Score"` or `"Safety Score"` or some other name.

If the column name is not in UPPER CASE in your table, you will need to surround it in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix by using the %%sql structure and the double quotes :

```
%%sql
select MAX("Safety Score") AS MAX_SAFETY_SCORE from Chicago_SCHOOLS;
```